# How can get Physical Address by pattern?

Tags: java, mac-address

I want get mac address WiFi computer by pattern recognition in java, but this putten give me all mac address(WIFI,Ethernet adapter....) Can help me get just  mac address wife.

```
     public static  GetMac() {
            byte[] macB = null;
            byte[] bytesEncoded = null;
            try {
                String command = "ipconfig /all";
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                BufferedReader inn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        p.getInputStream()));               
                //I want get just  mac address 
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*Physical Addres.*: (.*)");
                while (true) {
                    String line = inn.readLine();

                    if (line == null)
                        break;
                    Matcher mm = pattern.matcher(line);
                    if (mm.matches()) {
                        String macS = mm.group(1);
                        macB = macS.getBytes();
                        bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(macB);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Your problem is not a [`pattern recognition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition) problem. Remove [tag:pattern-recognition] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The simplest thing to do is to scan ipconfig result In which line containing mac id is preceded by* ->"Physical Address ...............:" *before mac id* " 00-00-00-00-00-00" .
**Find Index of** **":"** in that line add one to that and subtring of that index to length of file gives you the Mac 
[image: Output of ipconfig/all]

### Batch

```
@echo
off 
ipconfig /all 
pause
exit
```

### java code

```
 package test1;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 public class ProcessCommanLine {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ProcessCommanLine batchExecuteService = new ProcessCommanLine();
        ProcessCommanLine.run();
    }

    static void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String cmds[] = {"D:\\test1.bat"};
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runtime.exec(cmds);
            process.getOutputStream().close();
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedrReader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
            String strLine = "";
            while ((strLine = bufferedrReader.readLine()) != null) {
               // System.out.println(strLine);
                String ph="Physical Address";
                String subtring=null;
                if(strLine.length()>ph.length())
                subtring=strLine.substring(3,ph.length()+3); 
               if(strLine.contains(ph))
               {    
                   int i=strLine.indexOf(":")+1;
                   System.out.println(strLine.substring(i, strLine.length()));

               }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

### Output

[image: Mac]

Answer (score 0):

Hej, i do this on a Ubuntu System with this method:

```
public static String getMac(final String pattern) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ifconfig");
            InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.contains(pattern)) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SystemUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        String[] split = sb.toString().split("Adress");
        String macAddress = split[1].substring(2, split[1].length()-1);
        return "Your MAC of " + pattern + " is: " + macAddress;
    }
```

UPDATE:
This is a version with Pattern and Matcher usage:

```
public static String getMac(final String pattern) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ifconfig");
            Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile(pattern);

            InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Matcher m = regEx.matcher(line);
                if(m.find()) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SystemUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        String[] split = sb.toString().split("Adress");
        String macAddress = split[1].substring(2, split[1].length()-1);
        return "Your MAC of " + pattern + " is: " + macAddress;
    }
```

I call it with

```
System.out.println(SystemUtil.getMac("wlan"));
```

Maybe it helps.